# Issue to run single JUnit Test Suite from maven project (developed by Eclipse) via command line (maybe wrong search path)

Tags: maven, junit, command-line, automated-tests

Project:    SeleniumRCTestLibrary

```
System:     Windows 7 Enterprise SP1 x64
Maven:      Apache Maven 3.5.3
IDE:        Eclipse 4.7.3a (Oxygen.3a)
```

Environment/System variables:

```
JAVA_HOME       C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162
JAVA_PATH       C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\bin
classpath       C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\lib
path            included ";C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\bin"
```

Project structure:

```
SeleniumRCTestLibrary
|--src/main/java/com/dummy/jb/ (Own project libraries)
|--src/test/java/com/dummy/jb/ (Own Test Classes and Test Suites)
|  |--Main/Specs/*.java (Own Test Classes)
|  |--TestSuite/ (Own Test Suites)
|     |--Tenant/
|        |--ChannelX
|           |--TenantChannel_PlatformEnv_TestSuiteName.java (Single Test Suite to run)
|--JRE System Library (jre1.8.0_162)
|--Maven Dependencies
|--Referenced Libraries
|--src/
|--lib/ (Other libraries)
|--target/
|--pom.xml (Maven configuration file)
```

**Issue:**
In Eclipse 4.7.3a (Oxygen.3a) the given test suite runs succesfully (if I start the suite in jUnit 4 mode: Right click > Run As > Run configuration > Test runner: jUnit 4 > run).
But no runs if I use my local maven installation via command line:

1. cd to project directory
2. Command "mvn
   -Dtest=TenantChannel_PlatformEnv_TestSuiteName test"
   or "mvn -Dtest=TenantChannel_PlatformEnv_TestSuiteName test -X"

**Log:** without parameter "-X"

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ---------------< com.dummy.jb:SeleniumRCTestLibrary >---------------
[INFO] Building SeleniumRCTestLibrary 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.109 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-04-20T15:45:27+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Log:** with parameter "-X"

```
Apache Maven 3.5.3 (3383c37e1f9e9b3bc3df5050c29c8aff9f295297; 2018-02-24T20:49:05+01:00)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\Maven\apache-maven-3.5.3\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_162, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
[DEBUG] Created new class realm maven.api
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm maven.api
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.annotation.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.annotation.security.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.enterprise.inject.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.enterprise.util.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.inject.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.artifact < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.classrealm < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.cli < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.configuration < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.exception < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.execution < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.execution.scope < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.lifecycle < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.model < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.monitor < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.plugin < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.profiles < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.project < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.reporting < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.rtinfo < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.settings < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.toolchain < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.usability < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.authentication < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.authorization < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.events < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.observers < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.proxy < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.resource < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.classworlds < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.component < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.configuration < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.container < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.context < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.lifecycle < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.logging < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.personality < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.Xpp3Dom < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParser < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParserException < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlSerializer < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.artifact < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.collection < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.deployment < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.graph < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.impl < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.installation < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.metadata < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.resolution < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.spi < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.transfer < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.version < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.fusesource.jansi.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.helpers.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.spi.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG] Populating class realm maven.api
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[DEBUG] Message scheme: color
[DEBUG] Message styles: debug info warning error success failure strong mojo project
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from C:\Program Files\Maven\apache-maven-3.5.3\bin\..\conf\settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from C:\Users\cnorris\.m2\settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading global toolchains from C:\Program Files\Maven\apache-maven-3.5.3\bin\..\conf\toolchains.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user toolchains from C:\Users\cnorris\.m2\toolchains.xml
[DEBUG] Using local repository at C:\Users\cnorris\.m2\repository
[DEBUG] Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10.0 for C:\Users\cnorris\.m2\repository
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project com.dummy.jb:SeleniumRCTestLibrary:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: (none)
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecycle mappings for packaging pom from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[DEBUG] === REACTOR BUILD PLAN ================================================
[DEBUG] Project: com.dummy.jb:SeleniumRCTestLibrary:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG] Tasks:   [test]
[DEBUG] Style:   Regular
[DEBUG] =======================================================================
[INFO] 
[INFO] ---------------< com.dummy.jb:SeleniumRCTestLibrary >---------------
[INFO] Building SeleniumRCTestLibrary 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[DEBUG] Lifecycle default -> [validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle clean -> [pre-clean, clean, post-clean]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle site -> [pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy]
[DEBUG] === PROJECT BUILD PLAN ================================================
[DEBUG] Project:       com.dummy.jb:SeleniumRCTestLibrary:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG] Dependencies (collect): []
[DEBUG] Dependencies (resolve): []
[DEBUG] Repositories (dependencies): [central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, default, releases)]
[DEBUG] Repositories (plugins)     : [central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, default, releases)]
[DEBUG] =======================================================================
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.125 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-04-20T15:46:18+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Minimal project files, including the pom.xml file:**
[Click to download](https://www.java-forum.org/attachments/seleniumrctestlibrary-zip.10852/?temp_hash=58d61af2ea71048839098e3c47b3a653)

I think the maven environment find not the given test suite name.
In eclipse it works fine.

Comment: What is the command executed by eclipse ? You should be able to see it in the console

Comment: @Ko2r, not an mvn command line command. Too long for this comment

Comment: I need the correct mvn command for my shell scripts